# Check whether an image is packed (in python)

Tags: python, image

How to check whether an image is packed or not in python?

```
for i in bpy.data.images:
    if i.is_packed() :  ????
        do something
```

In https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html , `pack()` and `unpack()` is an action on image.

`packed_files` looks promising, but it lacks examples.

Comment: @batFINGER :: Thanks a lot of finding the duplicate.  ^^